Equivariant cohomology of fixed points using the localisation theorem
I am trying to understand the Smith-Thom inequality for spaces equipped with an action by a cyclic group and also the case, when it's an equality:
In the following, let $G=\mathbb{Z}/p$, $\mathbb{F}$ be a prime field of characteristic $p$ and $H_G^*(-)$ be the Borel construction for equivariant cohomology with coefficients in $\mathbb{F}$, i.e. $H_G^i(X):=H^i((X\times EG)/G;\mathbb{F})$ for a $G$-space $X$. I want to understand  why the following theorem holds:
Theorem 1 (Smith-Thom inequality) Let $X$ be a finite $n$-dimensional $G$-complex of finite orbit type. Then $\sum_i\dim_{\mathbb{F}}H^i(X^G)\leq\sum_i \dim_{\mathbb{F}}H^i(X)$, with equality if and only if the Serre spectral sequence of $X_G\to BG$ collapses at $E_2$ and $G$ acts trivially on $H^*(X)$.
In the literature, I have seen this stated as a direct consequence of the localisation theorem:
Localisation theorem Let $S=\{t^k\}_k$ where $t\in H^2(BS^1)$ is a generator. If $X$ is a finite dimensional $G$-complex, the inclusion $X^G\to X$ induces an isomorphism $$S^{-1}H^\ast_G(X)\to S^{-1}H^\ast_G(X^G).$$
For example in Hsiangs' book Cohomology theory of topological transformation groups, Theorem 1 is stated as a corollary of the Localisation Theorem (Corollary 2, Chapter IV.1, page 46)
There is also a proof given in Prop. III.4.16 in Tom Diecks Transformation groups using the following statement (Prop. III.4.9 in Tom Diecks' book):
Theorem 2 Let $X$ be a finite $n$-dimensional $G$-complex of finite orbit type. Then $H_G^k(X^G)\cong H^k_G(X)$ for all $k>n$.
In chapter III.4, Tom Dieck derives Theorem 2 from the localisation theorem by using a Gysin Sequence associated to the standard vector bundle (as he calls it) $$EG\times_G \mathbb{C}\to BG$$ which gives rise to an exact sequence
$$H_G^{r+1}(X\times S^1)\to H^r_G(X)\xrightarrow{\cup} H^{r+2}_G(X)\to H^{r+2}_G(X\times S^1)$$
I have the following question(s).
Question

Where does the last exact sequence come from?
Is there a different proof of Theorem 1, which does not use this standard vector bundle?


That looks like the Wang Sequence.

Actually it is the Thom-Gysin Sequence.

@JasonStarr so the Thom-Gysin sequence associated to the bundle $S^1\to X\times_G S^1\to X_G$? If yes, why is the action of $\pi_1X_G$ on $X\times_G S^1$ trivial so that we can apply the Thom-Gysin sequence?

@JasonStarr Also, if we have this Thom-Gysin sequence, the map $H_G^r(X)\to H_G^{r+2}(X)$ is given by the cup-product $t\smile (-)$ with $t\in H^2_G(X)$. But Tom-Dieck says that this map is the cup-product with some $t\in H^2(BG)$ (page 198 in Transformation Groups).

The $\mathbb{S}^1$-bundle over $X_G$ is pulled back from $BG$.  So the cohomology class is the pullback of the “first Chern class” of that circle bundle over $BG$.

Also, this $\mathbb{S}^1$-bundle over $BG$ is pulled back from a $\mathbb{S}^1$-bundle over $B\mathbb{S}^1$, and this space is simply connected.  So the derived pushforward of the constant coefficient sheaf $\mathbb{Z}$ is (quasi-isomorphic) to the complex of constant sheaves of the cohomology of the fiber.  So the hypotheses for the Thom-Gysin sequence are satisfied also on the pullback.

I am just posting my comments as one answer.
Let $\mathbb{S}^1$ denote the one-dimensional circle Lie group.  The classifying space $B\mathbb{S}^1$ is simply connected with integral cohomology ring isomorphic to the polynomial ring $\mathbb{Z}[c_1]$, where $c_1$ is the element of $H^2(B\mathbb{S}^1;\mathbb{Z})$ representing the first Chern class of the associated $\mathbb{C}$-line bundle over $B\mathbb{S}^1$ induced from the universal principal $\mathbb{S}^1$-bundle, $$\pi:E\mathbb{S}^1\to B\mathbb{S}^1.$$
In particular, $R\pi_*\underline{\mathbb{Z}}$ is quasi-isomorphic to a two-term complex of Abelian sheaves concentrated in degrees $0$ and $1$ whose zeroth cohomology sheaf and first cohomology sheaf are both isomorphic to the locally constant sheaf $\underline{\mathbb{Z}}$ on $B\mathbb{S}^1$ (the zeroth cohomology sheaf is canonically isomorphic to this, but the isomorphism of the first cohomology depends on an orientation of $\mathbb{S}^1$).  The induced Leray–Serre Spectral Sequence for $\pi$ reduces to a long exact sequence, usually called the Thom–Gysin Sequence of this principal $\mathbb{S}^1$-bundle, for all $n\geq 1$. $$\dotsb \to H^{n-1}(B\mathbb{S}^1;\mathbb{Z}) \xrightarrow{c_1 \cup -} H^{n+1}(B\mathbb{S}^1;\mathbb{Z}) \to H^{n+1}(E\mathbb{S}^1;\mathbb{Z}) \to \dotsb.  $$  Of course the total space $E\mathbb{S}^1$ is connected and contractible, so the long exact sequence reduces to the evident isomorphisms for $n=2m+1$ odd. $$\mathbb{Z}\cdot c_1^{m} \xrightarrow{c_1\cup -} \mathbb{Z}\cdot c_1^{m+1}.$$
Anyway, for every CW complex $B$, for every principal $\mathbb{S}^1$-bundle over $B$, $$\rho:E \to B,$$ there exists a continuous function $f_\rho:B\to B\mathbb{S}^1$ (unique up to homotopy) such that the pullback via $f_\rho$ of the universal principal $\mathbb{S}^1$-bundle $E\mathbb{S}^1$ is isomorphic to $E$ as a principal $\mathbb{S}^1$-bundle over $B$.  Thus, by the Proper Base Change Theorem in topology, the derived pushforward $R\rho_*\underline{\mathbb{Z}}$ is isomorphic to the pullback of $R\pi_*\underline{\mathbb{Z}}$.  This is quasi-isomorphic to a two-term complex concentrated in degrees $0$ and $1$ whose cohomology sheaves are both isomorphic to the locally constant sheaf $\underline{\mathbb{Z}}$ on $B$.  The terms in the induced Leray–Serre Spectral Sequence are naturally modules over the cohomology ring $H^*(B;\mathbb{Z})$.   Thus, as above, the spectral sequence reduces to $$\dotsb \to H^{n-1}(B;\mathbb{Z}) \xrightarrow{c_1 \cup -} H^{n+1}(B;\mathbb{Z}) \to H^{n+1}(E;\mathbb{Z}) \to \dotsb.  $$  Finally, for every Lie group $G$ (including a finite group with the discrete structure), for every continuous action of $G$ on a CW complex $X$, $$\mu:G\times X \to X,$$ for every morphism of Lie groups, $$\lambda:G\to \mathbb{S}^1,$$ set $B$ equal to $X\times^G EG$, and set $E$ equal to $(\mathbb{S}^1\times X)\times^G EG$, where the action of $G$ on $\mathbb{S}^1\times X$ is the diagonal action of $\lambda$ and $\mu$.  In this case, the spectral sequence above reduces to $$\dotsb \to H_G^{n-1}(X;\mathbb{Z}) \xrightarrow{c_1 \cup -} H_G^{n+1}(X;\mathbb{Z}) \to H^{n+1}_G(\mathbb{S}^1\times X;\mathbb{Z}) \to \dotsb.  $$

Thank you editor for the edits!

Like Andy's answer, this is about alternate proofs of the inequality in Theorem 1, which is, as was mentioned, perhaps due to Ed Floyd in a 1952 paper.
This Floyd theorem obviously implies the 1941 result of P. Smith: Smith Theorem: With $G$ and $X$ as in Theorem 1, if $X$ is mod $p$ acyclic, so is $X^G$.
In a paper that just appeared in Amer. J. Math., Chris Lloyd and I show that, curiously, this Smith theorem implies the Floyd theorem.
[One proves the contrapositive: if one had a $G$-space $X$ that contradicted the Floyd theorem, then one could find a $G$-space $Y$ that contradicted the Smith theorem.  $Y$ is constructed as a retract of $X^n$ for a well chosen $n$, with the retraction coming from the representation theory of the $n$th symmetric group.]
So assuming Smith's 1941 result, this is a very different proof of Theorem 1.
[Our argument is general enough that it also applies with mod $p$ homology replaced by various Morava $K$-theories, and the real goal of our paper was to say something new about the Balmer spectrum of $G$-spaces for some nonabelian $2$-groups $G$.]

Is the paper in question this one?  https://arxiv.org/abs/2008.00330

@AndyPutman Yes.

Since you also asked about alternate proofs of Theorem 1, there is a proof that does not use the localization theorem of a stronger version of the inequality (due to Floyd) in my notes Smith theory and Bredon homology.  See Theorem
B of those notes.
